# How to call stored procedure in preprocess query

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, parameters, visual-studio-lightswitch

I got a stored procedure that returns all data I need to view in a screen. My question is simple, how do I call the stored procedure, with a parameter?

```
partial void Query1_PreprocessQuery(int? UserSaveId, ref IQueryable<RuleEntry> query)
{
     query = ????   
}

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[FilterRuleEntriesByUserSaveId]
@userSaveId INT
AS    
BEGIN
WITH records
AS
.......
.......
SELECT  [One], [Two], [Three]
FROM    records 
WHERE   rn = 1
END
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/jj635144.aspx ?

Comment: @DavidTansey Yes I have, but I encountered some problems. "ConfigurationManager" is nowhere to be found in my project and what should I in that case assign "query" to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this, if you're **displaying** data, is with a custom RIA Service.

This article shows you how to create a RIA Service in LightSwitch (although it's geared around creating a chart, it shows you all the techniques that you need).

[How Do I: Display a chart built on aggregated data (Eric Erhardt)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lightswitch/archive/2011/04/08/how-do-i-display-a-chart-built-on-aggregated-data-eric-erhardt.aspx)

Some additional info on executing stored procedures in LightSwitch (although not exactly your scenario, it may help you understand the concept).

But once you create a RIA service, you can do just about anything you want, including using the technique described in David's link.

[Executing a Simple Stored Procedure in LightSwitch](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eric_erhardt/archive/2012/04/17/executing-a-simple-stored-procedure-in-lightswitch.aspx)

To access *ConfigurationManager*, you'll need to add a reference to *System.Configuration.dll*, if it's not already added. Then in your code you'll need a *using/imports System.Configuration* statement.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, RIA services are the only way to use stored procs in lightswitch.

I also found that if building an RIA service on top of an entity data model then the RIA service class has to be in the same project (assembly) as the EDM. If not, LS cannot use the RIA service.